# AWS SQS doesn't trigger expecting Lambda stepfunctions , not processing all messages in queue

Tags: aws-lambda, bigdata, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions, aws-sqs-fifo

I have configured sqs on s3 bucket, the sqs should invoke 21 stepfunctions for 21 files uploaded in s3 bucket, instead only 14 stepfunctions are triggered and i am missing remaining 7 events.

The moment i upload 21 files in s3 bucket, these, messages will be pushed to sqs, which will trigger lambda. I have set lambda concurrency to 5. So first 5 step functions should start. Since we uploaded 21 files, total 21 step functiins should  execute in batches of 5. Now, 14 step functions are running one after other instead of 21

**lambda code**

```
import json
import boto3
import os
import uuid
import time



client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
ipparam ={}
delay_seconds = 5
max_retry = 3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print('event',event)
    record = event['Records'][0]
    body = record['body']
    s3EventBody= json.loads(body)
    s3EventBody= s3EventBody['Records']
    
    bucket = s3EventBody[0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = s3EventBody[0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    
    
    #bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']
    #object_key = event['detail']['requestParameters']['key']
    
    ipparam["bucket"] = bucket
    ipparam["key"] = key
    
    print('bucket',bucket)
    print('key',key)
    
    transactionid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    

    for retry_attempt in range(1,max_retry+1):
        
        try:
            response = client.start_execution(
                stateMachineArn=os.environ['stepFunctionArn'],
                name = transactionid,
                input=json.dumps(ipparam)
                )
            print('responssee',response)
            executionArn =  response['executionArn']
            break
    
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error Invoking step function : ",e)
            if retry_attempt < max_retry:
                print('retrying in seconds : ',delay_seconds )
                time.sleep(delay_seconds)
            else:
                print('Max retries exceeded. Please check logs for further details')
                raise
    
    for i in range(1,15):
        response = client.describe_execution(
            executionArn=executionArn
            )
        execution_status = response['status']
        print('execution_status',execution_status)
        
        if execution_status in ('SUCCEEDED','FAILED'):
            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': execution_status
                }
        time.sleep(60)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4hMo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPK1i.png)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, your code only processes the first record in the array of records. So you are likely getting multiple SQS messages in each Lambda function invocation. And possibly multiple S3 events in each SQS message.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html